# Javascript show/hide table row based on Dropdown

Tags: javascript

I am having the most bizarre problem.  I want to hide a table row based on a selection from a drop down.  This is my code, but the problem is, it is adding "display: none" to the drop down, not the table row.  I have pulled out hair trying to figure this out, and I'm hoping somebody can help.

```
      <table><tr>
    <th>Clean Type</th>
    <td>
        <select id="selectType" name="selectType" class="textbox" onfocus="calcCheck()" onchange="toggle()">
            <option value="First Time Clean" <?php if($selectType == "First Time Clean"){ echo "selected";}?>>First Time Clean</option>
            <option value="New Car Clean" <?php if($selectType == "New Car Clean"){ echo "selected";}?>>New Car Clean</option>
        </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
        <tr id="contents1">
            <th>Clean Options</th>
            <td>
    <div id="contents2">
                <input name="polish" type="checkbox" value="" rel="100.00" onchange="calcCheck()"  <? echo $polish ?> /> <?=translate('polish')?><br />
                <input name="shampoo" type="checkbox" value="" rel="125.00" onchange="calcCheck()"  <? echo $shampoo ?> /> <?=translate('shampoo')?>
    </div>
            </td>
        </tr></table>


    <script type="text/javascript">

       function toggle() {

            const $selectType = document.getElementById("selectType").value ;
                            
            if($selectType.value == "New Car Clean") {
                document.getElementById("contents1").style.display = 'none';
            }
            else if($selectType.value == "First Time Clean") {
                document.getElementById("contents1").style.display = 'table-row';
            }
        }
```

Comment: You have an unwrapped elements in your HTML that should be wrapped in a `<table>` (or `<tbody>`). This may be just what you copied from your site, but please make sure you don't create problems that don't already exist when you compose your question. Also, there are far better ways to align content than using large amounts of `&nbsp;` characters.

Comment: The &nbsp; are just temporary, and yes, this is all in a table, but the rest of the table is irrelevant to this problem.

Comment: I'm not asking for the rest of the `<table>`, but I am specifically asking you to post valid HTML (otherwise you're creating a problem that didn't already exist, and undermining your own question by doing so).

Answer (score 0):

-html

```
<select
  id="selectType"
  name="selectType"
  class="textbox"
  onfocus="calcCheck()"
  onchange="toggle(value)"
>
  <option value="1">First Time Clean</option>
  <option value="2" selected>New Car Clean</option>
</select>
```

-javascript

```
function toggle(value) {
  const content = document.getElementById("contents1");
  if (value == "1") {
    content.style.display = "none";
  } else if (value == "2") {
    content.style.display = "table-row";
  }
}
```

---

onchange function in input,select element there is argument value, so you don't have to get value of element like below.

```
const $selectType = document.getElementById("selectType").value;
```

I think this answer can help you even a little.

If any other question, don't hesitate to ask.